# Работа с Picasso(Android), загрузка в ресурсы

Tags: java, android, picasso

Подскажите, как можно загрузить изображение не в ImageView а в папку с ресурсами либо установить загруженное изображение сразу в качестве фона Activity/Fragment'а

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Загрузить что-то в ресурсы в момент исполнения программы невозможно - ресурсы упаковываются в `apk` файл в момент компиляции.

Отобразить загруженную картинку в виде фона просто. Для этого загрузите картинку и в колбэке окончания назначьте фон нужному элементу разметки [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29777471/3212712):

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.table_background).into(new Target(){

  @Override
  public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom from) {
     mainLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap));
  }

  @Override
  public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
      Log.d("TAG", "FAILED");
  }

  @Override
  public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
      Log.d("TAG", "Prepare Load");
  }      
});
```